# Reboot server while HP SmartArray P410i array transformation?

Tags: linux, hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array, expansion

Just added two more drives to a 4 drives RAID 1+0 array on my ML350 G6+SA P410i+FBWC.
I also have to add an expander card (yes, I should have begun with it :/ ) but the array expansion takes a long time.

- So, I'm wondering if I can halt the server to plug the board and have the transformation continue upon restart?
- Can a server be rebooted while an array transformation?
- Could the addition of the expander board mess the array configuration if added while the array is transforming?

Comment: I can't tell you for certain, but I can say that I rebooted a server once while in a "rebuilding" phase and it had only lost a single drive in a RAID 10 (so not full loss of the array).  Next thing I knew I was restoring from backup because the controller got confused and lost the array completely.  So if it were me I'd simply wait.

Comment: @TheCleaner thank you for your lightning fast answer... and indeed it seems safer to wait !

Answer (score 4):

You can reboot under normal conditions... you shouldn't for the reason you plan to, though. Changing the port order (which the HP expander card *will* do) is risky mid-transformation.

Wait for the array transformation and make your changes once everything is settled.

Answer (score 4):

I really wouldn't - when I first read your question I thought you meant could you reboot the OS midway through the operation and the answer to that is yes - but I really wouldn't power off the server mid-operation at all sorry, you really could kill the array.